# how to run ros on raspberry-pi and another machine

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want  to run a talker node on my ubuntu and subscriber "listener node " on raspberry pi on raspbian
I already set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the ip of my raspberry pi and nodes are run correctly but it doesn't subscribe anything :\

this is my roswtf output

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory: 
 * /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
ERROR: Unknown host [raspberrypi] for node [/rosout]
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rosout:
   * /rosout


Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /rosout

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/rosout/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rosout/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://raspberrypi:33201]
 * service [/rosout/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/rosout/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://raspberrypi:33201]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227234/how-to-run-ros-on-raspberry-pi-and-another-machine/) by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-21**:
Can you provide more information.
Which machine are you running roscore on, have you run roswtf, what does rqtgraph show you when you run it

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-02-21**:
I have my laptop with ubuntu and raspberry pi with raspbian ..
roscore running on raspberry pi ..
I export ROS_MASTER_URI as pi roscore for my laptop and pi
,when I run talker node on my laptop it run correctly
and a listener node run correctly too on raspberry pi
but it doesn't listen to the talker

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-02-21**:
I updated my question with the roswtf output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably, you are not setting the ROS_IP (or ROS_HOSTNAME): http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on 2016-02-21**:
yes it was the problem ..thanks :)
and it is explained here http://answers.ros.org/question/188047/no-data-from-ssh-connection/